# How to reload dataTables from VueJS after adding or editing?

Tags: vue.js

I'd like to know how I can use this same approach when loading data from database through an api. In the first time the dataTables loads fine. However, when I add a new record, then I need to load my dataTables again with the new record. Here's my html code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-eventos">
    <thead>
        <tr class="tbheader">
            <th class="text-center">#</th>
            <th>Nome do Evento</th>
            <th class="text-center">Editar</th>
            <th class="text-center">Deletar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="ev in eventos" :key="ev.id" track-by="id">
            <td class="text-center">{{ ev.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ ev.name }}</td>
            <td class="text-center"><a class="cursorpointer" v-on:click="showMessage()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
            <td class="text-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And here's my VueJS code:

```
mounted() {
  this.getEventos();
},

methods: {
    getEventos() {
        axios.get('/api/eventos')
             .then((response) => {
                this.eventos = response.data})
             .then((response) => {
                $('#dataTables-eventos').DataTable({
                    responsive: true,
                    "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                    "aoColumnDefs": [
                        { "bSortable" : false, "aTargets": [0,2,3] },
                        { "searchable": false, "aTargets": [2,3] }
                    ],
                    language: {
                        url: '/js/dataTables/localization/pt_BR.json'
                    }
                });
             });
},

addNewRecord() {

    axios.post('/api/eventos', { nomeEvento: this.nomeEvento });

}
```

So after adding (or editing) a new record on my DB how can I reload my dataTables so I can see the changes?

Comment: Could you provide code for the whole vue app?

Comment: Seems like `axios.post(...).then(() => this.getEventos())`

Comment: Hi @RoyJ, thanks for your response, however your approach dos not work.  The dataTables is already created so I cannot call this.getEventos() again.

Comment: Sorry but stackoverflow does not allow me to add the whole vue code.

Comment: Maybe this would help? https://github.com/njleonzhang/vue-data-tables

Comment: What kind of problem do you have with adding your whole Vue ap? Is it too long? What error do you get?

Comment: Yes, the code is too long! Stackoverflow only allows up to 600 characters.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into a situation where I needed to use vue.js with datatables.net and had to use customized table html. I created a component that allowed me to format the table as I needed using template/v-for and refresh the datatable while preserving datatables.net functionality. I hope this helps someone down the road...

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            dataTable: null
        }
    },
    props: {
        data: Array
    },
    watch: {
        data() {
            if (this.dataTable) {
                this.dataTable.destroy();
            }

            this.$nextTick(() => {
                this.dataTable = $("#table").DataTable({
                    language: {
                        emptyTable: "No Results Found"
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without reloading all the data.
Just add *this.nomeEvento* to array *eventos* after posting to server.

Comment: Hi, I think that's a good idea, however in this case I also need to return the new Event ID as I'm using the ID on my dataTables. Do you know how I can get the last ID from DB using Laravel? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey, I managed to get the last inserted id, however here's what happened when I added the new event to my array.

Comment: Hey, I managed to get the last inserted id and added the new event to my array.

    this.eventos.push({
        id: response.data.evento_id,
        name: this.nomeEvento
    });

It does show the the new event on my dataTables, but it doesn't go into the right position (my dataTables is initially sorted by event name).

Also, if initially I have, let's say 20 records on my dataTables it shows at the table's footer the following:

   Showing 1 to 10 of 20 records.

And now when I add a new record it does not actually updates the dataTables. I have to refresh my screen.

Comment: "this.eventos.push" add your item in last position. If you want, you can sort out your array as you want after uploading to the server

Comment: Well, I tried sorting the table, but  it didn't work. As I said, when I add a new row it seems that dataTables doesn't recognize it. That's why initially I asked how to reload the dataTables. Remember I'm using jQuery dataTables and not my own table array! I have tried different commands such as:

    $('#ev').DataTable().push({
        "id": response.data.evento_id,
        "name": this.nomeEvento
    });
$('#ev').DataTable().clear();
$('#ev').DataTable().destroy();
$('#ev').DataTable().draw(false);

And none of them seems to work.

Comment: It is not practice to use jQuery with VueJS. May be you'll try to create table without jQuery?

Comment: Well, and do you know how to do that? I mean, manage a data table using Vue JS? I would appreciate if you can share some code on how to accomplish that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, I will try to use it. Thanks a lot.